# concatenating multiple values using Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables as following

**JobPost_Master1_UT**

```
JobPost_ID  JobPost_Name
-----------  -----------
1            .Net Developer
2            Java Developer
```

**Skillset_Master_UT**

```
Skill_ID     SkillName 
-----------  -----------
1            Javascript
2            Bootstrap
3            HTML
4            .Net MVC
5            JSP
```

**JobPost_Skill**

```
JobPost_ID  Skill_ID     
-----------  -----------
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             3
2             5
```

I want this result

```
JobPost_ID   SkillName
-----------  -----------
1            Javascript,Bootstrap,HTML
2            HTML,JSP
```

I am trying this

```
DECLARE @SkillName VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @SkillName = COALESCE(@SkillName ,'') + SkillName + ',' 
FROM JobPost_Skill
     left outer join Skillset_Master_UT
          on Skillset_Master_UT.Skill_ID =JobPost_Skill.Skillset_ID
     left outer join JobPost_Master1_UT
          on JobPost_Skill.JobPost_ID =JobPost_Master1_UT.JobPost_ID
group by JobPost_Master1_UT.JobPost_ID, @SkillName
```

But it gives me following result

```
SkillName
-----------
1  Javascript,Bootstrap,HTML,HTML,JSP
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a query like the following

```
SELECT JobPost_ID , STUFF((SELECT ',' + T1.Skillname
                           FROM  Skillset_Master_UT T1 INNER JOIN 
                                  JobPost_Skill T2 ON T1.Skill_ID = T2.Skill_ID
                            WHERE T2.JobPost_ID = TBL.JobPost_ID
                            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Skillname
FROM JobPost_Master1_UT TBL
```

Comment: @Ash if it working fine. You have to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) so the question is marked as answered